# Not understanding UseEffect rendering

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

In my useEffect, I sort an array based on a users input.
I created an extra useState const `[tempFlights, setTempFlights] = React.useState([]);` that I only use in my UseEffect.  This is a .js file not a .jsx file (I am working on another persons code base).
In my useEffect I update `setTempFlights` and my date for `flights` updates, when I remove the update for `setTempFlights`, `flights` isn't update until the next time the user chooses an input.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./index.style.css";
import FlightSearchItem from "./FlightSearchItem";
import FlightSearchFooter from "./FlightSearchFooter";
import useFetchFlightResults from "./useFetchFlightResults";
import SortBy from "./filters/SortBy";
import { SortByDefaultOption } from "./filters/SortBy/enums";

export default function FlightSearch() {
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState(SortByDefaultOption);

  // Fetch Flights
  const { flights } = useFetchFlightResults();
  const [tempFlights, setTempFlights] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = [];
    if (sortBy.value === "PRICE_LOW") {
      temp = flights.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
      setTempFlights([...temp]);
    } else if (sortBy.value === "BEST") {
      temp = flights.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
      setTempFlights([...temp]);
    } else {
      temp = flights.sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          new Date(a.segmentsArray[0].arrivesAt) -
          new Date(b.segmentsArray[0].arrivesAt)
        );
      });
      setTempFlights([...temp]);
    }
  }, [sortBy]);

  // Only show 10 flight results per page
  let paginatedFlights = flights.slice(0, 8);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="pane m-t-1">
        <div className="pane-header search-results__header">
          <div className="search-results__title">
            <b>Select an outbound flight</b>
            <p className="m-v-0 fade small">DEN → CHI</p>
          </div>
          <SortBy value={sortBy} onChange={setSortBy} />
        </div>
        {/* Display Flight Results */}
        <div className="pane-content">
          {Array.isArray(paginatedFlights) &&
            paginatedFlights.map((flight) => (
              <FlightSearchItem key={flight.id} flight={flight} />
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Pagination */}
      <FlightSearchFooter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see that the page updates based off of flights not tempFlights.
What is going on here and how can I change it to not need `setTempFlights([...temp]);`

Comment: To answer your last question, you would want to modify your `useFetchFlightResults` hook to accept arguments that would do the sorting. At some point, it would probably be necessary, since your dataset isn't necessarily going to contain all the data to apply a sort to. Just trying to convey modifying the fetch() hook is likely the right place.

Comment: Your useEffect fires when sortBy changes. Your `tempFlights` value is not being used anywhere. It looks like you're trying to set the state of an unused state variable to trigger the component to refresh, which is like "coding via side effects," which is obviously not a good idea. Your component should be updated when `flights` change, or you can set `flights` as the initial state of a useState, and then use that state variable in your return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort()` mutates the original array (flights in this case). This is why you are seeing updates even though you aren't using `tempFlights`. Oftentimes when using `sort`, you would create a copy of the original array beforehand to avoid mutating it.

```js
const tempFlights = [...flights];
tempFlights.sort()
```

In the above, `tempFlights` ends up sorted and `flights` is left alone.

If I were rewriting your snippet, I wouldn't use an effect at all. The resulting array can easily be derived from the selected sort value and doesn't need to be held in state separately.

```js
const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState(SortByDefaultOption);

// Fetch Flights
const { flights } = useFetchFlightResults();

const getTempFlights = () => {
    let temp = [...flights];
    if (sortBy.value === "PRICE_LOW") {
      temp.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    } else if (sortBy.value === "BEST") {
      temp.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
    } else {
      temp.sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          new Date(a.segmentsArray[0].arrivesAt) -
          new Date(b.segmentsArray[0].arrivesAt)
        );
      });
    }
    return temp;
}

const tempFlights = getTempFlights();

// Render logic as before
```

You could wrap `getTempFlights` in a useMemo hook if you're worried about recalculating the array each render, but it is often not consequential with typical data sets